# Putting Character Nodes in Alphabetical Order within a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, character, alphabetical

I have been trying to figure out how to do this for a while now and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. What I need to do is create a linked list using characters, and display the list in alphabetical order.

Main Program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String n = null;
    char newChar = ' ';
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();

    Node start = null;
    Node last = null;
    Node temp = null;

            do{
                System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
                newChar = reader.readChar();

                temp = new Node(newChar);

                if (start == null)
                     start = temp;
                if (last != null){ 
                    last.nodeptr = temp;
                }
                last = temp;

                System.out.print("Linked list: ");
                printList(start);

                System.out.print("Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? ");
                n = reader.readLine();
                addLine();

            }while(n.compareTo("y") == 0);

            System.out.println("The following will output a linked list created in alphabetical order.");
            addLine();

            start = null;
            last = null;
            temp = null;

            do{
                System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
                newChar = reader.readChar();

                temp = new Node(newChar);

                if(start == null){
                    start = temp;
                    last = temp;
                }

                //~~ CAUSING ISSUES ~~
                //if(last != null)
                    //last.nodeptr = temp;


                //insert before
                if(temp.letter < start.letter){
                    temp.nodeptr = start;
                    start = temp;   
                }

                //insert at middle or end
                else{
                    if(last.letter < temp.letter){
                        last.nodeptr = temp;
                        temp = last;
                    }
                    if(last.letter > temp.letter){
                        temp.nodeptr = last;
                        last = temp;
                    }
                }

                //For testing purposes
                /*else{
                    if(temp.letter > start.letter){
                        if(start.nodeptr != null){
                            while(temp.letter > start.nodeptr.letter){
                                temp.nodeptr = start;
                                start = temp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(temp.letter < last.letter){
                        if(last.nodeptr != null){
                            while(temp.letter < last.nodeptr.letter){
                                last.nodeptr = temp;
                                last = temp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                */

                System.out.print("Linked list: ");
                printList(start);

                System.out.print("Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? ");
                n = reader.readLine();
                addLine();

            }while(n.compareTo("y") == 0);
}
```

Current Output(as is with commented out stuff):

```
Enter a letter: m  
Linked list: m  
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y  

Enter a letter: o  
Linked list: mo  
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y  

Enter a letter: n  
Linked list: mon  
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y  

Enter a letter: e   
Linked list: mone  
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y  

Enter a letter: y  
Linked list: money  
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? n  

The following will output a linked list created in alphabetical order.  

Enter a letter: m  
Linked list: m  
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y  

Enter a letter: o  
Linked list: mo  
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? y  

Enter a letter: n  
Linked list: mn  
Would you like to enter another letter (y/n)? n
```

I figured out the first part of the program, which was just to insert as the user input each character. However, now I have to put it in alphabetical order and I think I pinpointed my issue, which I believe is due to the Last node. I commented it out in the program and it runs, however not correctly. If I leave it un-commented, it makes a loop and basically breaks the program.

If someone could help me fix the code up and make it work 100%, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically four cases to consider when you're adding a new character to your list:

1. If the list is empty, the new character becomes both the head and the tail of the list.
2. If the new character precedes the node at the head of the list, then it becomes the head of the list and points to the old head of the list.
3. If the new character occurs after the node at the tail of the list, then it becomes the tail of the list and the old tail node points to it.
4. If none of these are true, then the node goes somewhere in the middle of the list.

Cases 1 and 2 look correct as you have them:

```
if(start == null){
    start = temp;
    last = temp;
}

//insert before
if(temp.letter < start.letter){
    temp.nodeptr = start;
    start = temp;   
}
```

Case 3 has a slight bug:

```
if(last.letter < temp.letter){
    last.nodeptr = temp;
    temp = last;
}
```

Instead of `temp = last`, I think you want `last = temp` here, as `temp` is supposed to take its place as the last node in the list. This is why, when you type "N" after having entered "M" and "O", the "O" has disappeared.

Case 4 is the one you're going to need to do some work on. Because the new node could go anywhere in the list, and the list could have any number of elements, you're not going to be able to do it with just a series of `if` statements as you've done so far. Instead, you'll need to use a loop to traverse the list and find the appropriate place to insert the new node. Is this enough to get you going?

Comment: So for the 4th case, I will have to use a while statement right? I think I messed around with it in the part where I commented it out: For testing purposes. Would it be similar to that?

Comment: Correct: you need to use a `while` loop to walk through the list. However, your commented-out code is changing the value of `start` or `last` on every iteration of the loop, and you don't want to do that. There should be exactly one iteration of the loop that makes any change to the list: the one that identifies the correct location for the new node. You'll probably need to declare a new `Node` variable to represent the list node that you're examining currently.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to play around with it a bit in the morning. Hopefully I can figure it out, if not I'll probably post back here again with a comment tomorrow. Thanks for the help Joe!

Comment: So as of right now, I can't figure out why the code the list is stopping after just two characters are inputed by the user... I changed the temp = last to last = temp, however now it just displays "mo" and not "mn" after entering an n.

Comment: Have you written the code for case 4 yet? That's the one that needs to insert N into your list, so that would be why you aren't seeing it.

Comment: If you just want to test that the first three cases are working, enter a letter that comes after O as your third character and make sure all three show up.

Comment: Ohhh, no I haven't haha I think the fact that I wasn't seeing it distracted me from writing the 4th case.  I will write the 4th case and see if that's the fix! Thanks

Comment: Yeah so I just tested that and it actually doesn't work for a letter being pushed to the end. Not sure what's going on with it now, since if I put in "m" then "o" the "o" doesn't even get printed out...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75656/discussion-between-joe-farrell-and-moneydog11).